# The spring in my front dérailleur is jammed

Tags: chain, derailleur, gears, sprocket

My front derailleur is jammed by dirt (grease + fine dust), because of this the gear doesn't shift perfectly and chain is thrown off the cog. The spring is a bit unreachable because the derailleur arm comes in the way. How should I clean the spring and protect it from jamming again.

Comment: You can just remove the derailleur, it's not that difficult.

Comment: I have done that many times but this time the spring is sunk in dirt and that is just not coming off. thats the problem here this has made the spring nearly loose all it's spring(iness).

Comment: how are you trying to clean the dirt off? a (not high pressure) hose, kitchen brush and bike cleaning fluid (i.e. degreaser) generally work for me.

Comment: Use a toothbrush.  (Not yours, your wife's.)

Comment: I am using degreaser and kitchen brush

Comment: You can take the whole derailleur off without opening the chain and give it a thorough cleaning and greasing. If you have the possibility of using compressed air (friendly garage!) you can blow out the remaining grit.

Comment: Well I would try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to my favorite cycle mechanic and he dropped kerosene on the derailleur and then brushed the dirt off easily.